# Methods of killing deamon threads in Tomcat, application won't start - How do you solve this?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I recently deployed a Grails-application on the Amazon EC2. I used MySQL and Tomcat (amongst other things).

As this was just for testing purposes I wanted experience "bad" situations so I removed my application folders from the web-apps while the application was still running and things like that.

When I finally removed all traces of my application I tried deploying a new version of it by dropping a new war-file in the web-apps folder.

The application wouldn't start due to 8080 already bound exception, after reading some blogs I ran into a explanation to this problem: daemon threads...

Now I used the:

```
pkill java
```

And that did the trick, my qestion is how do you guys out there handle this situation?

Comment: did you try doing  'sudo tomcat6 stop' before killing the process?

Comment: Yes I tried that. The thing is, I was trying to mess up and put myself in a bad situation, this was sort of an experiment. What I was looking for here was how other people solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to detect when Tomcat has died, make sure it's truly stopped (ie. not running at all anymore) and then restart the process, your best bet would be a heartbeat process of some sort. You could write a shell script to run on the same box as Tomcat that periodically makes a web request to a specific URL. If it gets the expected value, then everything is fine, but if not, then it would issue the kill command, wait, and restart -- or send you an email, take other action, etc. You want to make sure this process isn't a daemon thread launched by Tomcat for the reasons your outlined above (they keep running in some cases). Rather, I'd set it up as a script to run as a cron job every minute.

Of course, if you're running on AWS EC2, it would be better to have a tiny instance that does this monitoring for you. When it detects a Tomcat server has died, it would kill that entire EC2 instance and spin up a new one to replace it. AWS has command-line tools that you can use in scripts to achieve this type of management. This might be an even better solution, because then you're starting with a clean slate, so any modifications (like files wiped out) would be restored when you attach an EBS volume or machine image with your initial image of the server. The method above (running a script on the same server) isn't going to be able to easily detect and fix missing files or other changes that made thing go kaput in the first place.